# Can you leave a cooked ham in cooking water overnight and then bake the next day?

Tags: ham

I usually boil and bake my hams.  As there is a great deal to do on Christmas day, I'd like to prep as much as possible the day before. Would it be possible to boil the ham and leave it in the cooking water overnight before baking the next day, or would this negatively impact the texture? (I imagine it is fine from a safety perspective!) Many thanks.

Comment: The problem is that unlike you find a way to chill and reheat the whole pot really fast, it *is not fine from a food safety perspective*.

Comment: ...agree with @Stephie...why was my vote to close as a duplicate removed?

Comment: @moscafj Mine is gone too, but I also can't vote to close again. Some kind of bug?

Comment: @user141592 same....